# What does the filter keyword do in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I ran across some Powershell code using the `filter` command.  I've never seen this command, but it works basically like this:

[image]

It seems to behave as a function.  If I run `Get-Command filter` I get back `The term 'filter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` and `Get-Alias filter` also returns a similar message.  `Get-Help filter` just returns Cmdlets and Functions with the word Filter somewhere.  If I Google for "Powershell filter command", I just get a bunch of stuff about various commands with `-Filter` arguments and `Where-Object` syntax.

What is this command and what is it used for?  Is there documentation on it somewhere?  Thanks!

Comment: There's a post on ServerFault that covers this. Essentially a filter is a function with only a process script block. https://serverfault.com/questions/551805/powershell-performance-difference-filter-vs-function

Comment: What prompt is that a picture of?

Comment: @js2010 Powershell (Yea I know I use a lightning bolt as a prompt, I'm weird) ⚡⚡

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In short, a filter is a function only able to use the process-block. Based on that in can be used to manipulate (filter, modify...) pipeline objects. They also allow you to e. g. deliver pre defined filter function with a module, saving you the work of writing complicated `Where-Objects` script blocks 100 of times.

[about functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6)

> Filters

> A filter is a type of function that runs on each object in the pipeline. A filter resembles a function with all its statements in a Process block.
> The following filter takes log entries from the pipeline and then displays either the whole entry or only the message portion of the entry:

```
 filter Get-ErrorLog ([switch]$message)
 {
   if ($message) { Out-Host -InputObject $_.Message }
   else { $_ }
 }
```

This [link](https://4sysops.com/archives/the-powershell-filter-2/) offers good explanation about including some examples.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup, this was exactly what I was looking for.  Just saw the syntax and never seen it and Google wasn't much help.  I just like to learn when I see something I don't know..

Answer (score 10):

A **[`filter` definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#filters) is *syntactic sugar*** that **makes it easier to create - typically - *parameter-less* `function`s whose sole purpose is to *process input from the pipeline***, (the latter being represented by the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)), but without the need to explicitly declare a [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#piping-objects-to-functions) that ensures per-*input-object* invocation.

That is, for example:

```bash
filter Add-One { 1 + $_ }
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```bash
function Add-One { process { 1 + $_ } }
```

With either definition, the following sample command:

```bash
1, 2 | Add-One
```

would yield:

```bash
2
3
```

---

**Perhaps because of their limitations** (see below) and the limited syntactic convenience they afford, **`filter`s aren't widely used**.

---

###### Limitations of `-filter` definitions:

- As implied by the above, `filter` bodies are implicit `process` blocks, and therefore do not also support `begin`, `end`, and `clean` blocks, the way that [`function`s do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#piping-objects-to-functions)
- Because `filter`s operate on *pipeline* input only, you cannot pass the input they expect as *arguments*.

  - If you try nonetheless, your arguments will be *quietly ignored*, except if you expend extra effort - see next point.
- While not typical, you *may* declare - what should be *optional* - parameters, but note that:

  - The only way to prevent passing arbitrary *unexpected* arguments to your `filter` is by explicitly checking if `$args` is nonempty; e.g.

    ```bash
    if ($args) { throw "Unexpected arguments passed: $args" }
    ```
  - Making a `filter` an [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) function - which *implicitly* prevent passing unrecognized arguments - is *not* an option, because that would invariably require defining a pipeline-binding parameter *explicitly*, which defeats the purpose of using a `filter` to begin with.

Comment: An example in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.4#filters) shows usage of a parameter with a filter. Was it added since Sep 2021?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh, I took a shortcut in my original explanation; please see my update, which spells out the limitations in detail.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose by its name, it's intended to be used in a pipeline.  I don't see it used much.

```
PS C:\users\js> Filter plusone { $_ + 1 }
PS C:\users\js> Echo 1 | plusone
2

PS C:\users\js> Filter comma { '{0:n0}' -f $_ }
PS C:\users\js> 1234567890 | comma
1,234,567,890
```