# Ho do I wrap Where-Object in a helper filter?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, where-object

I have this code:

```
$resultset = $stuff | Where-Object { $_.Prop1.SubProp7 -eq 'SearchString' }
```

Very similar code is repeated quite a few times. (in a Pester test).

How can I wrap that code in a simple [filter helper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56446577/321013)?

```
filter Where-Subprop7($SearchString) {
  <#??#> | Where-Object { $_.Prop1.SubProp7 <#??#> -eq $SearchString } | ...???
}

$resultset = $stuff | Where-Subprop7 'SearchString'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would indeed appear to be as straightforward as:

```
filter _WhereMyKey($key) {
  $_ | Where-Object { $_.Prop1.SubProp7 -eq $key }
}
```

This code works fine for me in my Pester expression:

```
$($stuff | _whereMyKey 'X-123').User | Should -Match 'Joe'
$($stuff | _whereMyKey 'Y-123').User | Should -Match 'Jane'
```

I did not use the naming `Where-` because it is a reserved verb.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small function to generate the filter block:

```
function New-WhereSubprop7Filter {
    param($SearchString)

    return {
        $_.Prop7.SubProp7 -eq $SearchString
    }.GetNewClosure()
}
```

Then use like:

```
$resultset = $stuff |Where-Object (New-WhereSubprop7Filter 'SearchString')
```

The call to `GetNewClosure` will create a closure over the `$SearchString` variable, making the scriptblock "remember" the `'SearchString'` value passed when invoking `New-WhereSubprop7Filter`.