# How to invoke Powershell filter from another Powershell filter?

Tags: powershell

Suppose we have a PS filter X:

```
filter X([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$o)
{
    begin { Write-Host "Begin X" }
    process { "|$o|" }
    end { Write-Host "End X" }
}
```

Here is the result of running it:

```
C:\> 0..3 | X
Begin X
|0|
|1|
|2|
|3|
End X
C:\>
```

I want to write another filter Y which must invoke X internally. The desired output of running `0..3 | Y` should be:

```
Begin Y
Begin X
|0|
|1|
|2|
|3|
End X
End Y
```

Here is my current implementation:

```
filter Y([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$o)
{
    begin { Write-Host "Begin Y" }
    process { $o | X }
    end { Write-Host "End Y" }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work as I need:

```
C:\> 0..3 | Y
Begin Y
Begin X
|0|
End X
Begin X
|1|
End X
Begin X
|2|
End X
Begin X
|3|
End X
End Y
C:\>
```

Which is perfectly expected, because the correct implementation should be something like this:

```
filter Y([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$o)
{
    begin { Write-Host "Begin Y" ; InvokeBeginBlockOf X }
    process { $o | InvokeProcessBlockOf X }
    end { Write-Host "End Y" ; InvokeEndBlockOf X }
}
```

This is pseudo code, of course, but the point is - I must be able to invoke the begin/process/end blocks of the X filter individually and that would be the correct way to invoke filter from a filter.

So my question is - how can we invoke filter from a filter by individually invoking the begin/process/end blocks from the respective blocks in the outer filter?

Comment: It is implied Santiago's helpful answer, but just to state it explicitly: you're not using `filter`s the way they're intended: a `filter` is primarily meant to be a _parameter-less_ function whose body is an _implied_ `process` block; it is syntactic sugar for a special-purpose `function`, namely one that processes _pipeline input only_. Example: `filter foo { "[$_]" }; 1..5 | foo`

Comment: Thanks, I got it and changed my code. I will leave it as is in the question so that your comments stay relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a [SteppablePipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.steppablepipeline?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) to accomplish this, as far as I know. I'm also unclear on why you're using the [`filter` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2#filters) when what you're defining are actually [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2).

A `filter` is supposed to be a named [Script Block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2) which implicitly acts as a [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process). See [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69215694/15339544) for details.

I would advise you to change them for actual functions:

```bash
function Y {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        Write-Host "Begin Y"
        $cmd     = Get-Command X
        $wrapped = { & $cmd @PSBoundParameters }

        $steppablepipe = $wrapped.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $steppablepipe.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    }
    process { $steppablepipe.Process($InputObject) }
    end {
        $steppablepipe.End()
        Write-Host "End Y"
    }
}

0..10 | Y
```

Outputs:

```
Begin Y
Begin X
|0|
|1|
|2|
|3|
|4|
|5|
|6|
|7|
|8|
|9|
|10|
End X
End Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It look like Santiago's use of steppable pipeline is better for what you want to do. I was not aware that it existed.

I am leaving my answer anyway as it provide a different take on this anyway.

---

A filter is a kind of function. Functions are stored in the `$Function` automatic variable. You could use that to get the begin block from the AST and execute it.

Something like `([Scriptblock]::Create($function:X.Ast.Body.ProcessBlock.Extent.Text).invoke($o))`

**Complete example**

```
filter X([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$o) {
    begin { Write-Host "Begin X" }
    process { "|$o|" }
    end { Write-Host "End X" }
}

filter Y([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$o) {
    begin { 
        Write-Host "Begin Y"
        & ([Scriptblock]::Create($function:X.Ast.Body.BeginBlock.Extent.Text))
    }
    process { ([Scriptblock]::Create($function:X.Ast.Body.ProcessBlock.Extent.Text).invoke($o)) }
    end {
        Write-Host "End Y"
        & ([Scriptblock]::Create($function:X.Ast.Body.EndBlock.Extent.Text))
    }
}
```

**Output for `0..3 | y`**

```
Begin Y
Begin X
|0|
|1|
|2|
|3|
End Y
End X
```

Note, when testing, I had some error for the begin block with the use of

```
[Scriptblock]::Create($function:X.Ast.Body.BeginBlock.Extent.Text).invoke()
# The script block cannot be invoked because it contains more than one 
clause
```

so I switched it up with this instead.

```
& ([Scriptblock]::Create($function:X.Ast.Body.BeginBlock.Extent.Text))
```

(Not sure why yet, I'll have to investigate but in any case, this work)

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but steppable pipelines are indeed the right and _robust_ solution. Using the `.Invoke()` method to execute a script block in PowerShell code is best avoided, because it changes the semantics of the call in several respects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220711/45375) . A closer (but not complete) approximation would require you to call the created script blocks with `. ` (dot-sourcing), so that state created in the `begin` block is available in the calls to the `process` block.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that `filter`s shouldn't be used this way and that what the code in the question defines should really be `function`s. Finally, a quibble: `$function` isn't an automatic variable: Prefix `$function:` is a _namespace_ qualifier (a scope modifier of sorts), and `function` refers to a PowerShell _drive_ by that name, which allows access to all defined functions. `$function:X` - which returns the body of function `X` as a script block - is an instance of [_namespace variable notation_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375). The docs don't use that term, unfortunately.